# WinAPI. Можно ли форматировать текст в поле edit?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Есть обычное поле edit, которое работает только на вывод текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было бы не плохо чтобы нужные слова например выделялись жирным шрифтом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, там только замена шрифта целиком.
Используете RichEditText контрол, там возможности форматирования довольно широкие.

Comment: Также для win32/mfc предоставляется такая возможность через обработку сообщения NM_CUSTOMDRAW. Подробнее https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048(v=vs.80).aspx